# My php file is not getting results properly

Tags: php, variables, overriding

i am having trouble.

i write HTML and jQuery and set same **name** attribute in `<select>` tag and `<input>` tag.

```
<select name="questionBoxOne" id="questionBoxOne">
  <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a question</option>
  <option value="">---------------</option>
  <option value="custom">Create your own question</option>
  <option value="">---------------</option>
  <option value="My mother's maiden name?">My mother's maiden name?</option>
  <option value="The name of my first pet?">The name of my first pet?</option>
  <option value="My father's middle name?">My father's middle name?</option>
</select>
```

I use this area to show input box, if user select Custom Question option.

```
<div id="newQuestion">
  <input type="text" value="" id="questionBoxOne" name="questionBoxOne" />
  <a id="cancel">select question</a>
</div>
```

And i use jQuery codes.

```
 <script language="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#newQuestion').hide();

            $('#questionBoxOne').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === 'custom') {
                    $('#newQuestion').show();
                    $('#questionBoxOne').hide();
                }
            });

            $('#cancel').click(function () {
                $('#questionBoxOne').show();
                $('#newQuestion').hide();
            });
 </script>
```

as you can see in my earlier codes i am sending same **name** to my next *finish.php* file, but when i am trying this it isn't showing `<select>` option question but this codes show custion question.

please help how i resolve this issue.

Comment: OK I think your hiding the select item when what you want to do is disable it? Also more explaination about how you want it to behave. Also what does "as you can see in my earlier codes i am sending same name to my next finish.php file," mean earlier questions link maybe?

Comment: @Laurence Burke  -- i am trying then when someone select custom question option, input tag become active and user able to submit his/her question. but when user select any question from dropdown menu. the variable pass through finish.php..   But my problem is that when i select custom option input box display and pass the name="questionBoxOne" to finish.php but when i select question from drop down menu, then name="questionBoxOne" pass to finish.php empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I think I understand. You want to disable the name your not using at the time so here is some code

```
 <script language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#newQuestion').hide();
        $('#newQuestion input').removeAttr('name');
        $('#questionBoxOne').change(function() {
            if ($(this).val() === 'custom') {
                $('#newQuestion').show();
                $('#newQuestion input').attr('name','questionBoxOne');
                $('#questionBoxOne').hide();
                $('#questionBoxOne').removeAttr('name');
            }
        });

        $('#cancel').click(function () {
            $('#questionBoxOne').show();
            $('#questionBoxOne').attr('name','questionBoxOne');
            $('#newQuestion input').removeAttr('name');
            $('#newQuestion').hide();
        });
 </script>
```

that should work

but instead of the first removeattr from the #newQuestion you should remove the name attribute in the html
Yes AND ALSO VERY IMPORTANT GET RID OF THE ID FOR THE INPUT OF NEWQUESTION!!!

However the way in which you should handle this is

```
<form id="submit" action="finish.php" method="post">
   <select id="questionSelect" name="questionSelect">
         <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a question</option>
         <option value="">---------------</option>
         <option value="custom">Create your own question</option>
         <option value="">---------------</option>
         <option value="My mother's maiden name?">My mother's maiden name?</option>
         <option value="The name of my first pet?">The name of my first pet?</option>
         <option value="My father's middle name?">My father's middle name?</option>
   </select>
  <input type="text" value="" id="custQuestion" name="custQuestion" />
  <a id="cancel">select question</a>
```

then keep your original jquery functions with the ids changed to the appropriate ones like so

```
 <script language="javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#custQuestion').hide();

            $('#questionSelect').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() === 'custom') {
                    $('#custQuestion').show();
                    $('#questionSelect').hide();
                }
            });

            $('#cancel').click(function () {
                $('#questionSelect').show();
                $('#custQuestion').attr('value','').hide();
            });
 </script>
```

now on the finish.php you can look for both names returned and use the one depending if custom question is blank or not.

like so

```
if(!empty($_POST['custQuestion'))
  $question = $_POST['custQuestion'];
else
  $question = $_POST['questionSelect'];
```

now if that doesn't help you need to do more research

Comment: It won't quite work but you've got the right idea. Not your fault, he has the `questionBoxOne` id attribute on two elements (which is wrong and will cause errors), so you should use `$('#newQuestion input')` to select the text input, and OP should fix his error. Plus you need to set the text input disabled in the html as default. In other words, `#newQuestion` is the id of the div, not the input.

Comment: `#newQuestion` is a div, not an input.

Comment: METALMAN ROCKS wooot yeah look at it now

Comment: It still won't work because there are duplicate ids `#questionBoxOne`, it's OP's fault. OK, back to work for me, Good Luck with this :) **Get equipped with Metal Blade!!**

Comment: But however if he gets rid of the id for the input it should work. however this is very heavey handed jquery for something that can be handled on the PHP side to look for 2 different names on the Post or Get global

Comment: I agree, personally I never rely on javascript to be the backbone of a form, only enhancement. There's a million better ways to do this and still have it work with or without js.

Comment: Yes its working fine,,, Thank your very very much @Laurence Burke. but friend can you please tell me little bit whats wrong with my codes.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with your idea of naming conventions and best practices. ID's ARE ALWAYS UNIQUE!!! never stray from that principle. Next name's should be unique to a form but not always. What I usually do is keep names and ids the same WITHIN the element so there is never any duplication.